# How to show only selected cell of collectionView after 2-3 second of loading CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` with 60 item. while selecting item in collection i am navigating to next screen and there also i am showing horizontal `UICollectionView` and selected cell is highlighted there. now i want to implement after 2-3 second of view appear only selected item(which is highlighted) should show, rest should be invisible(or should not show)

Comment: show your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

First override delegate method and `didSelectItemAt` method

Than already you have a list of array of 60 items.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{

return list.count

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    addToList.append(objectsArray[indexPath.row])

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@objc func hideChannel() {

```
    if let channel = TVManager.shared.currentChannel {
        for item in 0...self.viewModel.channelCount {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)) as? PlayerCell {
                if cell.channelId != channel.id {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
                                           cell.alpha = 0.0
                                       }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```